# How to create an empty Android project in Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse

How I can create an Android project from the menu with an empty activity in Eclipse. I don't want title bar, icon in the top...nothing. A empty project with an empty avtivity.

Thanks

Comment: What kind of project are you trying to create?

Comment: Im novice and I want lo learn...so just I want an empty project with a white, blank, empty Activity.

Comment: or...how I can remove the title bar? In the code I dont see where is added.

Comment: You mean an Android project?

Comment: Yes, an Android project

Answer (score 2):

In order to create an android project using eclipse Goto `File --> New --> Android Application Project`. A new window open, in this window put your project name and click next and complete the process.

And to remove the title bar go to `src` folder and expand your project, then open your activity. In the code inside the `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` function add `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` before the `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

Comment: for more details regarding android please refer http://developer.android.com/training/index.html